# Formula for population variance, issues with placement?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

From trying to construct the formula by hand, I had come up with the following:

```
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n}
```

Now this looks fairly correct, however the `_i=1` and `^n` do not show above and below, rather above and right as you would expect it:

[image]

I cannot find an example or reference to find the correct one. What should be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `\sum` operator to have the limits `i=1` and `n` to be displayed above/below it, you need to add a `\displaystyle` in front of it:

```
\sigma^2 = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n}
```

[image: Displaystyle formula]

Comment: ... or `\limits` just after `\sum`, e.g., `\sum\limits`

Answer (score 4):

The following is an excerpt from **Section 2.4.4 Sums, products, unions, integrals, etc.** from Mathematics into Type by Ellen Swanson:

> **2.4.4a Sums and products**
>
> In text, the subscripts and superscripts usually follow the symbols,
> while in display they are normally printed above and below.

[image]

> In the past some publishers used to place subscripts and superscripts
> to the right of sums and products both in text and display to avoid
> extra typesetting costs. Aesthetically it is preferable to set them in
> display as shown above, and with modern computer typesetting systems
> it is no more expensive. In text, though, beware of expressions like

[image]

> where the prime has some specific meaning, and moving the N to the
> side may cause confusion.

For unions and intersections, the treatment is similar to that for sums and products.

For integrals:

> When a single integral is used, the subscripts and superscripts always
> follow the symbol. For multiple integrals used in display, the
> subscripts and superscripts may be centered above and below them.

In your particular case, you have three options if the formula is to appear displayed:

1. To leave the formula as it is.
2. To use `\displaystyle\sum` which will place the indices above and below and will also increase the size of the summation sign.
3. To use `\sum\limits` which will also place the indices above and below but without increasing the size of the summation sign.

The following code illustrates these options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n} \]

\[ \sigma^2 = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n} \]

\[ \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2} {n} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the formula is to appear in text, then it would be preferable to use something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text  text text text text  text text text text  text text text text 
$\sigma^2 = (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \mu)^2$ text text text text text text text text  text text text text  text text text text  text text text text 

\end{document}
```

[image]